Depending on one's philosophy, is Bayes' theorem actually an axiom?
In the frequentist philosophy, probabilities refer to the relative frequencies of our outcomes in a large number of trials. Using this definition, it is possible to prove Bayes' theorem as simply a statement about proportions of certain outcomes. So Bayes' theorem is a theorem in this philosophy.
Let's look at the Bayesian philosophy : Probabilities refer to the degree of belief that one has in a particular outcome. Now, there can be a subset of this philosophy where the primary method one uses to form beliefs is frequencies. E.g. the reason that such a Bayesian says that the probability of Heads is 0.5 is that, in their experience, Heads occur roughly half of the time. (I say primary method because I don't think frequencies can be a self-sufficient method to form beliefs, as some situations are fundamentally non-repeatable).
Within this subset of Bayesianism philosophies, one can again prove Bayes' theorem, as probabilities again refer to frequencies.
But the above is a subset of Bayesian philosophies. In general, the Bayesian probability is a "degree of belief", which need not have anything to do with frequencies.
Therefore, is it correct to say that Bayes' theorem essentially becomes an axiom about how to update one's beliefs? When this axiom is identical to the standard Bayes' formula, the interpretation of the probability or the "degree of belief" is compatible with frequentism. But in general, we are allowed to pick a different axiom.
P.S. One can also prove Bayes' theorem from Kologmorov axioms by defining P(A|B):= P(A and B)/P(B). But this is just a definition of P(A|B). The status of P(A|B) as the "degree of belief in A given B"  essentially becomes an axiom of Bayesianism.
Essentially, what I'm saying is that there is nothing about the characterisation of probability as a "degree of belief" that picks Bayes' theorem as the method to update those beliefs.

@Conifold i think that, in principle, one can also have different betting strategies. e.g. consider a random coin about which it is known that, in the limit of large trials, the ratio of the square of the number Heads and the total number trials $(n_H)^2/(total trials)$ tends to converge to 0.5. The process is otherwise completely unpredictable. Suppose when a Bayesian says "my degree of belief in Heads is 0.5", they mean that they expect $(n_H)^2/n$ to converge to 0.5. I think this process cannot be modelled by a Frequentist betting strategy

@Conifold Maybe the success of Frequentist betting strategies and the standard Bayes' theorem is that the random process that we empirically encounter in nature are well modeled by a frequentist model of randomness

Bayes' theorem is just that: a theorem of probability theory. It is neutral as to the interpretation that one gives to the concept of probability. The distinctive thing about Bayesianism is that it uses conditional probabilities as updating rules, as you say. When you apply considerations of what constitute rational beliefs then frequencies are relevant because it is rational to proportion your belief to the evidence, i.e. to calibrate your degree of credence against known frequencies.

@Bumble yes... i think the updating rule P(A|B)=P(A and B)/P(B) essentially becomes an axiom of Bayesianism philosophies. I agree that it is rational to base your belief in frequencies, using which one can derive this updating rule. But also, if seems like the Bayesian school leaves room open for other methods of forming and updating beliefs, as  it doesn't use "frequencies" in its definition of probabilities and just leaves it at "degree of belief"

@Bumble in a world where there is randomness but the frequencies don't show any long term convergence behavior, one would have to develop more general methods of modelling randomness and beliefs. I think the success of the standard frequency-based approach is because many empirically known random processes tend to show a convergence in frequencies and hence can be modelled by a frequency based approach

I would rather say that P(A|B) = P(A and B)/P(B) is not an updating rule: it is simply the definition of conditional probability, or perhaps a constraint upon it. The updating rule is that the probability of A that results from being updated by the information B is P(A|B). Sometimes you will see the probability of A updated by B written as P(A||B) or as PB(A).

@Bumble yes, that's what I meant to say. That P(A||B) is chosen to be equal to P(A|B) is an axiom. I think this axiom can be justified for random processes that are well modelled by frequencies, combined with a definition of  "degree of belief" in terms of frequencies. But, in general, Bayesianism seems to allow other frameworks too, as it leaves the nature of "degree of belief" unspecified.

There's some problem using the common Kolmogorov probability as degree of belief or credence as hinted by Solomonoff's incomputable universal prior of any evidence which is necessarily a semi-measure due to the halting problem with the sum of all possible evidences' prior must be less than 1, or perhaps far less than 1  like absorbed by some dark matter predicted by contemporary cosmology theory. There seems something structurally ontologically preceding probability which should be the right measure of our degree of belief and if it's true then Bayesianism becomes a misnomer...

@DoubleKnot interesting. Can you link any paper about this?

See Solomonoff probability: Formally, the probability P is not a probability and it is not computable. It is only "lower semi-computable" and a "semi-measure"... That is, the "probability" does not actually sum up to one, unlike actual probabilities. This is because some inputs to the Turing machine causes it to never halt, which means the probability mass allocated to those inputs is lost. And semi-measures cannot avoid the Dutch-book...

Apart from this there are also pretty serious problems if you see Bayes rule as model for how humans (or science in general) updates their beliefs. Conditionalizing cannot really deal with forgetting information or with negative evidence. Michael Titelbaum tries to solve those problems in "Quitting Certainties: A Bayesian Framework Modeling Degrees of Belief". (I didn't find this entirely convincing, though - even though the formal framework seemed fine.)

@mudskipper thanks for the reference. Also, I think of Bayes' theorem as closer to "how an ideally rational human should update their beliefs" rather than as a model of how a human actually update their beliefs. But even then, there seems to be a lot of work required to make the Bayesian framework well defined. E.g. how many times in a row must a coin must a coin produce Heads for me update my belief from "The coin is fair" to "The coin is not fair"? Should humans use a threshold number for this, or should the belief be shifted continuously? I will make a separate post about this

@RyderRude - The main thing is not that one should use Bayes to update one's beliefs, if one want to be rational (=to optimize), but that we can only do so in one-shot applications where we have clean data and well-defined probabilities. So, as a general model of belief update (and especially as a normative model) Bayes is pretty useless, imo, and as a former ML engineer I'm rather surprised by the philosophical interest in it. Seems to me largely misguided.

Bayes' Theorem is a direct consequence of the definition of conditional probability:

Thus, P(A ∩ B) = P(A|B) * P(B) = P(B|A) * P(A).
Thus, we arrive at P(A|B) = P(A ∩ B) / P(B) = P(B|A) * P(A) / P(B), or

Bayes' Theorem is founded on the axioms of probability theory. Therefore, to apply Bayes' Theorem meaningfully in epistemology, the axioms of probability theory must hold within the epistemological domain where you intend to use it.
There must exist a probability space, with A and B defined as events. If the concept of a probability space cannot be meaningfully applied to your epistemological problem, you risk venturing into a domain where the axioms underlying Bayes' Theorem no longer hold. If you do that, any "probabilistic" conclusions drawn from using a tool outside its intended scope are up to you, since this is not even a probability space to begin with, which makes even talking about "probability" questionable in principle. It would be like trying to apply the Pythagorean theorem to non-Euclidean geometries.

But even if we have a real world experiment where there is set of possible events and a probability measure on it, such that the Kologmorov axioms are satisfied,  there is nothing about the Kologmorov axioms that picks out P(A|B)=P(A and B)/P(B) ( and by extension Bayes' theorem) as the way to update our beliefs

if interpret the Kologmorov probabilities as just a "degree of belief", then no belief update rule is picked out by that definition. If we set the update rule to be identical to the standard rule, then the interpretation of "degree of belief" becomes compatible with frequentism. But in general, Bayesianism seems to allow for other rules too.

@RyderRude This answer seems quite relevant. Check it out. See also this (which supports the frequentist interpretation/intuition). See also this, which seems to agree with you that it can be seen as an axiom. My general undertanding is that P(A|B)=P(A ∩ B)/P(B) is a definition, so it doesn't need proof. But it can also be interpreted as the probability of A ∩ B under the new sample space B, and in that case it should be a theorem as per the first link.

@RyderRude Now, you raise a valid point as to why use that definition instead of any other conceivable definition for belief updates? Arguably because it makes a lot of sense and is consistent with many intutions and approaches to conditional probabilities. But sure, in principle someone might be interested in studying a completely different definition instead of the usual one.

I think Bumbe in a comment above gave a nice technique to avoid this confusion. Let's define P(A|B) as the formula P(A and B)/P(B). And define P(A||B) as "the updated degree of belief in A, given that B is true". Then the axiom : P(A||B)=P(A|B) defines a subset of the Bayesian philosophies. In this subset, Bayesianism more or less agrees with frequentism, as this specific belief update rule is compatible with a frequentist interpretation of probabilities, like your second link derives. But, in general,  a Bayesian may define "degree of belief" differently.

@RyderRude Right, but as soon as you depart from the original definition by employing a different one, this would no longer be Bayes' theorem (which has a specific formal statement tied to the standard definition of conditional probability), and by that point I don't think talking about "Bayesianism" would even make sense. It would not be Bayesianism, it would be something else. A new term would need to be coined to disambiguate, and you would need to prove that the theorem holds under the new proposed definition.

I'm not sure if this is standard but I separate Bayes' theorem from Bayesianism. While Bayesianism was inspired by Bayes' theorem, I think Bayesianism is simply the statement that probabilities refer to one's degree of beliefs, while Bayes' theorem can either be seen as a theorem from Kologmorov axioms (in which case it has nothing to do with philosophy), or it can be seen as a way do update beliefs in a specific version of Bayesianism where the the degree of belief is defined in terms of frequencies

Bayes’s theorem is a theory in probability and nothing else. So no, to directly answer your question, it is not correct to say that Bayes' theorem becomes an axiom about how to update one's beliefs.
How you represent belief, and how you update belief, is a normative process. It is an epistemology that is ultimately a matter of philosophical opinion and has nothing to do with the pure mathematical structure of Bayes’ theorem.

I am thinking that it's more like the characterisation of $P(A||B)=P(A and B)/P(B)$ as the "belief update rule" is an axiom in Bayesianism. When we choose this belief update rule, Bayesianism becomes compatible with frequentism. But in general, Bayesianism does not pick out this particular rule

@RyderRude - The problem is not just should we use Bayes' rule to update some belief (given that we want to be "rational"), but can we use it. Bayes rule involves a huge idealization + simplification. It cannot simply be used continuously to trace how the belief(s) in some proposition evolve (or should evolve) over time, when the evidence (the prior) is an independent variable which is not just given once.

Apart from that, it remains pretty much unexplained how or why to choose any particular prior.

An answer from a comment by Conifold:

Almost. Bayesian epistemology can be formalized as probabilism thesis (credences are Kolmogorov measures) combined with the conditionalization rule for updating them in the simplest case. Bayes's theorem for general updating can then be derived as a consequence, see SEP, Bayesian Epistemology. However, Dutch book arguments show that we are not 'allowed' to pick a different updating rule if we put our money where our mouth is (base bets on credences), and do not wish to lose in the long run.

